# Is there a better way to write this script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, optimization, google-classroom

I'm trying to add students to Google Classrooms ('Courses') from a Google Sheet with code below (function AddStudents).

It's very slow and, if I do too many, it exceeds allowed execution time.  Is there anything that I can do to speed it up?

```
function AddStudent(argStudent, argCourseCode) {
  Classroom.Courses.Students.create({
    userId: argStudent,
  }, argCourseCode);
}


function AddStudents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var shtStudents = ss.getSheetByName('Students');

  var rngStudentCourses = shtStudents.getRange(2,6,645,2);
  var arrStudentCourses = rngStudentCourses.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < arrStudentCourses.length; i++) {
    AddStudent(arrStudentCourses[i][0], arrStudentCourses[i][1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Classroom API can request with the batch request. When this can be used, the process cost will be able to be reduced. But in the current stage, the official document says `The Classroom API is currently experiencing issues with batch requests. Use multithreading for heavy request loads, instead.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch)

Comment: So for example, how about requesting the endpoint using the fetchAll method? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests) The fetchAll method can work with the asynchronous process. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728) So your goal might be resolved.

Comment: If your code works fine and objective of this post is to have optimization and code improvements, [Code Reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right forum for you